# Injecting a class depending on args

Tags: java, guice

I need to construct a ApplicationContext instance using Guice. Most of my other classes depends on ApplicationContext. However, ApplicationContext depends on the args array available in public static void main.

Currently, I have to create ApplicationContext and call the setters by hand, then inject it with injectMembers before asking Guice to create other objects. Is there a better way to get my object created by Guice when it depends on args?

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ApplicationContext();
// configure my appContext from command line args
injector.injectMembers(appContext);
MyAppFoo a = injector.getInstance(MyAppFoo.class);
a.doThings();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use providers or provider methods to construct `ApplicationContext` and configure it before it participates in other injections:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(b -> {
        b.bind(ApplicationContext.class).toProvider(() -> {
            // construct and configure application context
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ApplicationContext();
            ctx.setSomething(args[0]);
            ctx.setSomethingElse(args[1]);
            return ctx;
        }).in(Singleton.class);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it:

```
class ApplicationContext {
    @Inject @Named("args") String[] args;
}

class MyAppFoo {
    @Inject ApplicationContext context;
}

class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String[] args;

    ApplicationModule(String[] args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(String[].class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named("args"))
            .toInstance(args);

        bind(ApplicationContext.class);
        bind(MyAppFoo.class);
    }
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule(args));
        MyAppFoo a = injector.getInstance(MyAppFoo.class);
        a.doThings();
    }
}
```